# How do I get my discord bot to list out an embed of all discord members in my server?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my discord bot to display all members that is in my server, but it only shows the object, how do i get it to display the members? Here's the code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def memberlist(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Server name", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Member List:", value= ctx.message.server.members, inline=False)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to coding and I want to finish this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can join the elements of `members` with `", ".join(ctx.message.server.members)`.  Try using that as the `value` in the embed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I tried what you suggested, but I got an error: (discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Member found) how do I fix this?

Comment: `", ".join(str(member) for member in ctx.message.server.members)` then.

Comment: Oh! Thanks sooo much for the help! It works now! Is there a way to mention the users?

Comment: Every `Member` object will have a `member.mention` attribute.  `", ".join(member.mention for member in ctx.message.server.members)`

Comment: Thanks soo much again!